# Countable synonyms for "prey"?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, countable-nouns

Even though the word *prey* is used as an opposite of *predator*, the former not as grammatically versatile as the latter, in terms of **number**:

> A predator is ambushing its prey.

> A prey (?) is being ambushed by a predator.

> Two predators are ambushing their prey.

> Two preys (?) are being ambushed by a predator.

Is *prey* ever countable? Could *two preys* work at all? I've heard someone use *prey animals* which could work because *animal* is very much countable. But I hope there's a better alternative

Comment: I racked my brain, but came up only with other uncountable synonyms: *quarry*, *game*.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I hate to burst your bubble, but those two words seem to suffer from the exact same deficiency that *prey* does. *Game* is uncountable in the particular sense of "prey for sport".

Comment: A [thesaurus](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/prey.html) includes *kills, targets, prizes, victims.*

Comment: @Vun ... read my comment carefully, I know they are uncountable, that's why I commented and am not passing that off as an answer at all.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark oh sorry abt that. I must have missed that "un-"

Comment: Weather Vane's selections are all good - but it depends if the OP is writing something scientific and neutral, whether their sympathies are with prey or predator, and whether the prey is killed and/or eaten, chased unsuccessfully, or something else. Predator and prey (or prey animals) are the usual terms in [scientific](https://www.nature.com/scitable/knowledge/library/dynamics-of-predation-13229468/) [writing](https://besjournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/1365-2656.13139), but outside that you have more freedom.

Comment: You may have to settle for **"a prey species"**.

Answer (score 3):

You could also use ***quarries***:

> **QUARRY**
> plural *-ries*
> an animal, bird, or fish that is hunted, esp by other animals; prey ([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/quarry))

[FreeDictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/quarry) defines it as

> ***quarry*** n. pl. ***quarries***
> 1.
> a. A hunted animal; prey.
> b. Hunted animals considered as a group; game.

***[Game](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/game)*** is also a term used in hunting, but it is uncountable.

As for the plural of *prey* it does exist, but it is not so common and is rather used in particular contexts:

> The noun ***prey*** *can be countable or uncountable*.
>
> In more general, commonly used, contexts, *the plural form will also* be
> ***prey***.
>
> However, in more specific contexts, *the plural form can also be **preys***
> e.g. in reference to various ***types of preys*** or a ***collection of preys***. ([WordHippo](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/the-plural-of/prey.html#:%7E:text=The%20noun%20prey%20can%20be,Find%20more%20words!))

[M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prey) confirms:

> plural ***prey***, also ***preys***

This [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=their%20preys%2Ctheir%20quarries&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) will show you that both ***their quarries*** and ***their quarries*** are used, although much less then the singular forms.

Comment: Your quote from Collins isn't what it says: ***3. singular noun** A person's or animal's quarry is the person or animal that they are hunting.* The plural is for the quarry where minerals etc. are extracted.

Comment: @WeatherVane You need to scroll down. You will find the definition as quoted.

Comment: I see, so Collins contradicts itself? Or does it present all the alterntives it can find from other resources?

Comment: I believe the plural in M-W must pertain to the obsolete usage meaning booty, or plundered spoils. And I wouldn't rely on WordHippo, which blithely provides a plural for *luck* in the same way.

Comment: @TinfoilHat yes Wordhippo is a useful source for associations and ideas, but those should be followed up.